# What is the right way to use c++17 standard with cmake in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2022

I have came over from Visual Studio project to CMake not a long time ago, but I have one problem. I have bunch of IntelliSense only (the build works normally) errors, which are partially caused by not activated c++17 standard, and partially not recognizing members of structures that are in the code.

## Top level cmakelist:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
project ("VulkanCMake")

add_subdirectory ("VulkanCMake")
```

## The project one:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)

find_package(glfw3)
find_package(Vulkan)

include_directories("vcpkg includes")
include_directories("Vulkan include dirs")


add_executable (VulkanCMake "VulkanCMake.cpp" "VulkanCMake.h")

target_link_libraries(VulkanCMake Vulkan::Vulkan)
target_link_libraries(VulkanCMake glfw)

target_compile_features(VulkanCMake PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
```

Comment: I doubt Intellisense will pick this up from CMakeCache.txt. Or - I don't think cmake will create a sln with the C++ standard provided in the Intellisense options. You might have to do it manually.

Comment: Oh, OK, I'll try that

Comment: Neither of those `include_directories` calls do anything useful at all. And you should avoid calling that function, anyway.

Comment: Update cmake and use modern CMake style. This is CMake from 20 years ago. Set properties on targets and not as global vars. If you can apply modern CMake practices - look for them on google, watch some talks on YouTube and apply them to your project. It's too big of a topic to discuss in a comment and you might not want that, so I stop right here.

Comment: I recommend using Premake (https://premake.github.io/). It is MUCH better!